# sed to edit yaml file with individual values to each key

Tags: linux, bash, sed, yaml

I have a yaml file and shell script to edit the values of yaml file.

```
#YAML
UI:
  repo: my-repo-1
  imageTag: ui-image:v1
DB:
  repo: my-repo-2
  imageTag: db-image:v1
```

```
#!/bin/bash
sed -i "/^\([[:space:]]*imageTag: \).*/s//\1$1/" test.yaml
```

On running the script to change the tag of UI with **./script.sh ui-image:v2** is changing the imageTag of both UI and DB with value "ui-image:v2".

How can I make a change in the script so that I can pass individual tag to both UI and DB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can limit the replacement for `$1` to "from UI: to imageTag:" and similarly for `DB:` and `$2`:

```
sed -i -e "/^UI:/,/imageTag:/{/^\([[:space:]]*imageTag: \).*/s//\1$1/}" \
       -e "/^DB:/,/imageTag:/{/^\([[:space:]]*imageTag: \).*/s//\1$2/}" \
       test.yaml
```

Comment: So, I can replace my script file with the above two lines right? And where do I pass the yaml filename?

Comment: @KumaranRaj: Updated to answer your questions.

Comment: Thanks @choroba If there is a parent tag App for UI and DB, where should I pass that?

Comment: To ask a new question, ask a new question